# Tomcat stops because of too many requests...Configuration seems not to be applied

Tags: linux, tomcat, server, request, out-of-memory

when sending mass notification to my mobile app users my tomcat instance just freezes or stops! After looking into the logs I find some interesting information:

```
Exception in thread "http-nio-8080-ClientPoller" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

and

```
WARNUNG [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} 
Setting property 'maxConnection' to '20000' did not find a matching proper
```

**My Tomcat Configuration (server.xml)**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxThreads="10000"
           maxConnection="20000"
           acceptCount="10000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

It seems that my configuration was not applied...did I forget something?

**My Server specifications:**

```
 - Virtual Linux server (Ubuntu 18)
 - 60 GB RAM
 - 1,500 GB SSD
 - 16 vCores
```